# Renaming Computer by executing Bat Files

Tags: powershell, python, batch-file, wmi

I am trying to create a FAST API to change the name of the system by executing the bat files. The name gets changed but its not accepting special characters like `-`, `,` and `'`.

I have searched a lot but didn't get any solution for it.
I have tried executing the PowerShell command but it asks for admin access.

Here is my bat file code:

```
@ECHO OFF
### For Admin Previleges
set "params=%*"
cd /d "%~dp0" && ( if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ) && fsutil dirty query %systemdrive% 1>nul 2>nul || (  echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) : UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/k cd ""%~sdp0"" && %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && exit /B )

set arg1=%1
set arg2=%2

wmic computersystem where caption='%arg1%' rename '%arg2%'

move nul 2>&0
```

Here is my python code for executing batch files:

```
def set_Computer_Name(computer_name : str):
    current_computer_name = platform.node()
    process = subprocess.run(['computer_name.bat', current_computer_name, computer_name])
    return {"status" : process.returncode}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You probably need to escape those character.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem please don't forget to [accept it by clicking the green check mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png) on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you elevate/run-as-admin your python process first, then your subprocess will also be elevated. Then you can run `Rename-Computer` normally instead of trying to manage special characters through three languages:

```
# python running as admin
process = subprocess.run(['powershell.exe', 'Rename-Computer', computer_name])
```

If you can't elevate python for some reason, you can use powershell instead of batch to elevate its own child process:

```
process = subprocess.run([
  'powershell.exe', 
  'Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb runas', 
  '-ArgumentList { Rename-Computer -Newname', computer_name, '}'
])
```

And to be clear about special characters, windows computer names must be characters `a-zA-Z`, and may include `0-9` or `-`. Characters like `'` or `,` are not allowed.

---

One exception to basic elevation happens when the computer is joined to a windows domain. The user must have both local administrator rights, **and** rights to the computer object in AD. It's common to elevate using just a local admin user, so I mention it here.